# Printing Specific Elements from a Nested List

Tags: python

I have a nested list that looks like this:

```
 [['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'],
 ['Thorny', '100', '90', '80'],
 ['Mac', '88', '99', '111'],
 ['Farva', '45', '56', '67'],
 ['Rabbit', '59', '61', '67'],
 ['Ursula', '73', '79', '83'],
 ['Foster', '89', '97', '101']]
```

I was able to pull out student names using the following:

> ```
> `def get_students(grades):
>     student_names = []
>         for i in range(1,len(grades)):
>     student_names.append(grades[i][0])
>     return student_names  `
> ```

The output was `['Thorny', 'Mac', 'Farva', 'Rabbit', 'Ursula', 'Foster']`

Now I need to pull out the "Exam" headers. I used similar code but it is getting very different results.

> ```
> `def get_assignments(grades):
>     exam_list = []
>         for i in range(6, len(grades)):
>     exam_list.append(grades[0][1 : ]) 
>     return exam_list`
> ```

This returns the output:

```
`[['Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3']]`
```

I have been looking here and at GeeksForGeeks to try and figure out what I am doing wrong. It seemed like it should be a simple tweaking of the first code to access a different part of the nested list but I can't seem to get it. Any tips would be appreciated.

EDIT: Apologies, my problem may not have been clear. The desired output is

> ['Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3']

Thank you!

Comment: `for i in range(1, len(grades)): exam_list.append(grades[i][1:])`

Answer (score 0):

this is a short solution with list Comprehension

```
lst=[['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'], ['Thorny', '100', '90', '80'], ['Mac', '88', '99', '111'], ['Farva', '45', '56', '67'], ['Rabbit', '59', '61', '67'], ['Ursula', '73', '79', '83'], ['Foster', '89', '97', '101']]
lstStudents=[nlst[0] for nlst in lst]
lstExams=[nlst[1:] for nlst in lst[1:]]

print(lstStudents)
print(lstExams)
```

the out put will be:

```
['Student', 'Thorny', 'Mac', 'Farva', 'Rabbit', 'Ursula', 'Foster']
[['100', '90', '80'], ['88', '99', '111'], ['45', '56', '67'], ['59', '61', '67'], ['73', '79', '83'], ['89', '97', '101']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider turning your data in to a list of dictionaries, then we can make use of Python's list comprehensions to retrieve whatever you need.

```
grades = [['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'], ['Thorny', '100', '90', '80'], ['Mac', '88', '99', '111'], ['Farva', '45', '56', '67'], ['Rabbit', '59', '61', '67'], ['Ursula', '73', '79', '83'], ['Foster', '89', '97', '101']]
headers = grades[0]
grades_list = [dict(zip(headers, student)) for student in grades[1:]]

print(*(grade for grade in grades_list if grade['Student']=='Rabbit'))
# Output {'Student': 'Rabbit', 'Exam 1': '59', 'Exam 2': '61', 'Exam 3': '67'}
```